# What is the meaning of the "mage_catalog_compare_item" Database-Table in Magento 1.5?

Tags: database

In my Magento Database I have a table named `mage_catalog_compare_item`. For what is this table good? It has some entries and the columns are:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| catalog_compare_item_id | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| visitor_id              | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| customer_id             | int(11) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id              | int(11) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| store_id                | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Is this related to a store-customer related comparison feature? It seems so to me, but as I'm new to Magento I don't know and I have problems to find out more, as the table name does not seem to be documented specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the looks of the table name, when your Magento was installed `mage_` was set as a database table prefix.

This table is used to store the products compared by a visitor and it's found in all Magento versions.
When you add a product to comparison, a record is inserted in this table.

`catalog_compare_item` is the name of the table, because of the `mage_` prefix, in your case it's called `mage_catalog_compare_item`

Comment: Right, so this was my noobish approach then. I should actually search for the table name without the prefix in the future. Thanks for your feedback, this was exactly what I was looking for.